# What is the name for the very first Polish state likely established around 966 by Mieszko I through baptism of Poland?

Tags: europe, political-history, poland, helmet

In the year of likely around 966, Mieszko I united all of the tribes occupying a part of today's western Poland through Christianization of it, therefore making Poland an official sovereign state (at that time it was a Duchy though I did not find anything that would indicate that its official name was "Duchy of Poland").

26 years later, his son Bolesław I the Brave, became the new head of state and 59 years later transformed the country to a kingdom, crowning himself a king. From that day on the country during this period was officially called "Kingdom of Poland", but what was the official name of the country before that??????

Answer (score 5):

From the Wikipedia article on [Poland in the Early Middle Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poland_in_the_Early_Middle_Ages):

> Under duke Mieszko I of the Piast dynasty, the expanded Polan territory was converted to Christianity in 966, which is generally regarded the birth of the Polish state. The contemporary names of the realm, **"Mieszko's state"** or "**Gniezno state"**, were dropped soon afterwards in favour of **"Poland"** (or latinized as **Polonia**) , a rendering of the Polans' tribal name

The name "Poland" (*Polska*) comes from the name of the the tribe of western Polans - literally "people of the fields" ("pole" means both open area - plain - or an farming field) who became the dominant force around the 10th century in this region.

The first written notes about "Polonia" can be found around year 1000:

- [John Canaprius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Canaparius),a Benedictine monk at the Aventine monastery in Rome wrote about Soběslav, the brother of Saint Adalbert of Prague who went *cum Bolizlauo Palaniorum duce* (with Boleslaw, prince of Poland)
- One of the songs about Saint Adalbert says *Polania ergo tanti sepeliens floret martyryii pignora* (uhhh... Poland buries the body of the martyr?)
- *Annales Hildesheimenses* from 1003 mention *Heinricus Berthaldi comitis filius, et Bruno frater regis, et ambo Bolizavones, Polianicus vide licet ac Boemicus, a rege infideliter maiestatis rei deficient* (Heinric, son of Berhold and Bruno, brother of the king and both Boleslaws - Polish and Czech left the circle of the friends of the emperor)

Comment: Saint Adalbert was buried in Gniezno by Bolesław I.